# Burn basemap in favor of matplotlib-basemap

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, synonym-request

I ran into [Python Basemap "Assertion failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675734/python-basemap-fails) and noticed its tagged with [matplotlib-basemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matplotlib-basemap) and [basemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basemap):

This is the summary for [basemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basemap) (35 questions tagged):

> The python matplotlib toolkit for plotting data and visualizations on
>   maps. (Synonymous with matplotlib-basemap)

Here is [matplotlib-basemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matplotlib-basemap) (199 questions tagged):

> The matplotlib basemap toolkit is a library for plotting 2D data on
>   maps in Python. It is similar in functionality to the matlab mapping
>   toolbox, the IDL mapping facilities, GrADS, or the Generic Mapping
>   Tools. PyNGL and CDAT are other libraries that provide similar
>   capabilities in Python.

Admittedly [basemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basemap) is the synonymous with [matplotlib-basemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matplotlib-basemap), but I don't see any other uses of it. A large majority of questions tagged with `basemap` either have matplotlib in the title, or are tagged with it as well.

So either it should really be a synonym  (currently it `matplotlib-basemap` [has no synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/matplotlib-basemap/synonyms)) or simply burn and retag.